# Forcing a particular order in Rails model scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a Model `M` in my rails code. It has a field `F` which can have 4 values `D`, `J`, `M` and `Z`

If I use a scope like this, it would sort data by field `F` alphabetically:

```
default scope {order (F: :asc)}
```

I have 2 questions here:

1. I don't want to sort data alphabetically on `F`. I would like data to be displayed with this particular order of `F` instead. I want ALWAYS the records containing value `M` for field `F` first, follow by records having value `J`,  `D` and then `Z` in this order. How can I achieve this?
2. Suppose I would like to display records having `J` first and then sort the rest of the records by alphabetical order of field `F`, how can I do that?

Comment: they are values of the column `F`. They are defined in table `M` in the database.

Comment: So what are the values of them? Constants must have values.

Comment: `D`, `J`, `M`, `Z` - they are the different values for column `F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort with a CASE statement

```
order("CASE WHEN F = 'M' THEN 0 WHEN F = 'J' THEN 1 WHEN F = 'D' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END")
```

Alternatively (if it's only "M" that needs to be first and the rest can be alphabetical)

```
order("CASE WHEN F = 'M' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, F")
```

Comment: I get an error `function array_position does not exist` when I tried the above. Aldo I could not find any article or documentation on this when I searched `array_position rails` in google

Comment: `array_position` is a `postgreSQL` feature.  I'll modify my answer to give a generic solution.

Comment: Ok, less compact but more generic, let me know how you get on.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks much! And sorry for the delayed response. I could get around to trying this out only just a few minutes back.